# How do I disable the coloured lighting in the viewport in 2.8?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, lighting, eevee-render-engine

When shaded in Look Dev mode, there's a kind of coloured lighting so the darker faces are yellow and the lighter faces are blue. Is there a way of disabling this so the shading is more greyscale like in 2.79? The faces of this cube should be in black and white only but the colours look very different in the viewport. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warm light comes from the studio light. You can either change to a different HDRI texture by clicking on the light probe image or enable *Scene World* to use the current configuration of the world background for Look Dev instead.

[image: Viewport shading]